# Read large mongodb data

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, morphia

I have a java application that needs to read a large amount of data from MongoDB 3.2 and transfer it to Hadoop.

This batch application is run every 4 hours 6 times a day.

**Data Specifications:**

- Documents: 80000 at a time (every 4 hours)
- Size : 3gb

Currently I am using **MongoTemplate** and **Morphia** in order to access MongoDB.
However I get an OOM exception when processing this data using the following :

```
List<MYClass> datalist = datasource.getCollection("mycollection").find().asList();
```

What is the best way to read this data and populate to Hadoop?

- `MongoTemplate::Stream()` and write to Hadoop one by one?
- `batchSize(someLimit)` and write the entire batch to Hadoop?
- `Cursor.batch()` and write to hdfs one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies at the `asList()` call

This forces the driver to iterate through the entire cursor (80,000 docs few Gigs), keeping all in memory.

`batchSize(someLimit)` and `Cursor.batch()` won't help here as you traverse the whole cursor, no matter what batch size is.

Instead you can:

1) Iterate the cursor: `List<MYClass> datalist = datasource.getCollection("mycollection").find()`

2) Read documents one at a time and feed the documents into a buffer (let's say a list)

3) For every 1000 documents (say) call Hadoop API, clear the buffer, then start again.

Answer (score 1):

The `asList()` call will try to load the whole Mongodb collection into memory. Trying to make an in memory list object bigger than 3gb of size.

Iterating the collection with a cursor will fix this problem. You can do this with the Datasource class, but I prefer the type safe abstractions that Morphia offers with the [DAO](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.4/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/dao/BasicDAO.html) classes:

```
  class Dao extends BasicDAO<Order, String> {
    Dao(Datastore ds) {
      super(Order.class, ds);
    }
  }

  Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, DB_NAME);
  Dao dao = new Dao(ds);

  Iterator<> iterator = dao.find().fetch();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Order order = iterator.next;
      hadoopStrategy.add(order);
  }
```